# XPath to look for subtree

Tags: xpath, lxml

I'm scraping an html document, whose structure changes all the time. Css class names even change, so I can't rely on that. However, one thing never changes, the value is always contained in a subtree exactly like the following:

```
<span>
  <span>
    <span>wanted value</span>
    <span></span>wanted value
  </span>
</span>
```

Can this be expressed as an XPath expression?

It should *not* match:

```
<span>
  <span>
    <span> 1, one too little </span>
    <span> 2 </span>
    <span> 3, one too many </span>
    <span> 4, two too many </span>
  </span>
</span>
```

I plan to do this using lxml for Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the location of the wanted value is always on the third level of span an xpath as follows will work:

```
//span/span/span[1]
```

When applied on the next HTML document:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Your Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
    <span>
      <span>
        <span>wanted value</span>
        <span></span>
      </span>
    </span>
    </div>
    <div>
    <span>
      <span>
        <span>wanted value</span>
        <span></span>
      </span>
    </span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The result will be:

```
wanted value
wanted value
```

***EDIT***

If you only want the values of the first span on the third level when the total of spans equals 2 on the third level you can use the following XPath:

```
//span/span[count(span) = 2]/span[1]
```

Comment: Your expression will also match where there are more than two innermost span elements, eg four span siblings, I would like it to match only when there are two.

Comment: @ThomasWessel: I don't quite understand what you mean. Can you expand / change your question or try to explain with HTML example documents and the desired output?

Comment: Updated with counterexample

Comment: @ThomasWessel: I still don't get it. When you apply the XPath: //span/span/span[1] to your example the result will be ' 1, one too little '. So the first occurence of span in the third level will be resulted. Isn't that what you want? What output do you expect?

Comment: It is a huge document, and there are several places with three nested spans. But only one of those subtrees, the one I'm interested in, has *exactly* two span elements in the "bottom layer". When there are exactly two, then I am interested in the first of those. If there is only one span element, or more than two, then I don't want any of it.

Comment: @ThomasWessel: XPath would then be: //span/span[count(span) = 2]/span[1]